# Why do these elements not fade / transition

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

I have made a little navigation, upon hovering above the home I want to let it slowly slide out to the left using a `transition: 0.4s;` but it doesn't want to do anything, I've applied it to every element just to show that it doesn't work no matter what.

Anyone knows how to fix this? Maybe it's because of the `position: fixed;` ?

I have made a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3ufoa48q/), keep in mind that it's only a snippet of my site, and has no esthetic style.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Transitions on the display: property](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3331353/transitions-on-the-display-property)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot make a transition on the `display` property.

Answer (score 1):

You can't put a transition on the `display` property.

Here is a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3ufoa48q/1/) that uses the transition on `max-width` to allow a transition to happen.

```
.desktopnav > ul > .dropdown > .dropdown-content {
    float: left;
    transition: max-width 0.4s;
    overflow: hidden;
    max-width: 0px;
}

.desktopnav >ul > .dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
    max-width: 500px;

}
```

you will need to had more css to hide undesired visual effect and force the list item to stay aligned on top.

Your use of ul/li is a bit off, `li` should only be children of `ul` elements, not `section` elements, and `ul` should only have `li` elements as children.

Comment: Thanks, for the help!

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_animated_properties

This is a list of properties that can be animated. Display is not one of those. That's why you aren't seeing a transition.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot animate the `display` property. If you want to accomplish a "slide to left" effect, you have to animate the `max-width` property.

I've forked your fiddle to illustrate this: https://jsfiddle.net/w811wvfp/1/

Basically what I did was:

```
.desktopnav > ul > .dropdown {
    ...
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.desktopnav > ul > .dropdown > .dropdown-content {
    ...
    max-width: 0;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.desktopnav > ul > .dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    max-width: 1000px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that's what I wanted :)!